# Cordova: Capture Native Event in Web based Application or Javascript?

Tags: cordova, hybrid, sap-fiori

Can we capture Native Events in Web based Application or Javascript? e.g.: Can we capture Volume up and down event of phone and at same time do increment or decrement in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

if you look at cordova doc:
[Cordova events](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#volumedownbutton)
Just add following event listeners for volume buttons:

```
document.addEventListener("volumedownbutton", onVolumeDownKeyDown, false);
document.addEventListener("volumeupbutton", onVolumeUpKeyDown, false);
```